# iText Sign PDF with custom "Signed by" name

Tags: java, itext, certificate, itext7

I can sign a PDF using iText 7.

Now, I want to show a different name than the one which is in Certificate, like a surname (not only on the PDF itself with the appearance but also in the "Rev1: Signed by X" in Adobe).

This is the code that I use actually to sign PDF :

```java
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());

// Create the signature appearance
PdfPage page = signer.getDocument().getPage(1);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 120, 80);
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance().setReason(reason).setPageNumber(1)
.setLocation(location).setPageRect(rect);

signer.setFieldName("sig");

IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
IExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

// Sign the document using the detached mode, CMS or CAdES equivalent.
signer.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, signatureType);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask how *to show a different name than the one which is in Certificate, like a surname (not only on the PDF itself with the appearance but also in the "Rev1: Signed by X" in Adobe).*

This essentially are two questions at once, one on how to customize the text in the signature appearance on the document page and one on how to customize the text shown by Adobe Acrobat in its Signature Panel.

### Customize the Text in the Signature Appearance on the Document Page

Here you have essentially two relevant helpers:

- The `PdfSignatureAppearance` method `setLayer2Text` allow you to set the *description* text in the signature visualization. You can change its style using `setLayer2Font`, `setLayer2FontSize`, and `setLayer2FontColor`.
- The `PdfSignatureAppearance` method `getLayer2` returns a `PdfFormXObject` on which you can create a completely custom signature visualization. You can also use `getLayer0` to return a `PdfFormXObject` which serves as a background.

You can choose your helper depending on the degree of customization required.

### Customize the Text Shown by Adobe Acrobat in its Signature Panel

This is something else entirely. As this panel is outside of the document area, the PDF specification is not dictating the contents of that panel, it is up to Adobe what information goes there. Thus, what you hope to achieve can only to a certain degree be managed if at all.

Having experimented a bit using a fairly current Adobe Acrobat Reader it turns out that under certain circumstances the value of the **Name** entry of the signature dictionary (if set at all) is used here instead of certificate information.

You can set that entry using signature events like this:

```java
PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(...);
pdfSigner.setSignatureEvent(new PdfSigner.ISignatureEvent() {
    @Override
    public void getSignatureDictionary(PdfSignature sig) {
        sig.setName("A Custom Signer");
    }
});
...
```

Having signed with this addition Adobe Acrobat sometimes uses *"A Custom Signer"* instead of the certificate information in its signature panel.

- If you switch off automatic verification during opening in Acrobat Reader

  [image: Preferences]

  and then open the PDF, you see

  [image: Requires Validation]

  After explicitly requesting validation, you get

  [image: Valid]

  As you see, *"A Custom Signer"* all the time.
- If on the other hand you activate automatic verification upon opening in the preferences, you get

  [image: Automatically Valid]

  As you see, here information from the certificate is used.
- Furthermore, you get *"A Custom Signer"* always if Adobe Acrobat cannot properly read the signature (e.g. due to an unknown signing algorithm).

Comment: The first way (edit Signature appearance in PDF directly) works, and that's not really what I need (because it's difficult to show more than 40+ signatures on the same PDF ...).
The second way (edit Adobe view) don't work for me. I don't know what i'm doing wrong, I just test without editing appearance style. The event is well called, but does nothing.
It can be because of self-signed certificate ?

Comment: Did you configure your Adobe reader to not validate on loading?

Comment: Oh, so it works only when we validate signature manually :/ That's a problem because by default, Adobe set the option to true and so, by default, we don't see the good name.

Comment: Right, by default Adobe uses the certificate data. Currently! As mentioned in my answer, *it is up to Adobe what information goes there*, and apparently they currently use certificate data if available. I doubt you can change that default behavior for current Acrobat versions unless you make the signature container unreadable or choose a non-standard **SubFilter**. Either approach, though, surely defeats the purpose of signing.