# Digitially sign a PDF using java

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox, digital-signature

I need to digitally sign a pdf in java.

All My tracing links are taking me to c# references but I need in java [Java references required private key to sign but based on document and api response there are no private key].

Reference Link :
[Sign multiple location with same response xml signature in PKCS7 (CMS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55237425/sign-multiple-location-with-same-response-xml-signature-in-pkcs7-cms)
[How to sign digital signature in pdf using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70904124/how-to-sign-digital-signature-in-pdf-using-python)
[Why I am getting an error while opening digitally signed pdf document using PKCS7 and X509Certificate in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53313288/why-i-am-getting-an-error-while-opening-digitally-signed-pdf-document-using-pkcs)

As same as the above link i am getting the same xml response from API. Below is the sample of API Response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EsignResp errCode="NA" errMsg="NA" resCode="1233333333333312121" status="1" ts="2024-03-14T14:59:39" txn="reference-transaction">
    <UserX509Certificate>base64 value of eSign user certificate(.cer)</UserX509Certificate>
    <Signatures>
        <DocSignature error="" id="1" sigHashAlgorithm="SHA256">Signature data in raw (PKCS#1) or raw( ECDSA ) or PKCS7 (CMS) signature as requested
</DocSignature>
    </Signatures>
    <Signature
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></CanonicalizationMethod>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></SignatureMethod>
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform>
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod>
                <DigestValue>xxxxxxxx</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <KeyValue>
                <RSAKeyValue>
                    <Modulus>xxxxxxxxxxxx</Modulus>
                    <Exponent>xxxxx</Exponent>
                </RSAKeyValue>
            </KeyValue>
            <X509Data>
                <X509SubjectName>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</X509SubjectName>
                <X509Certificate>xxxxxxxxxx</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
</EsignResp>
```

As per API DOC:

- `UserX509Certificate` refers to **This element will contain the Base 64 value of the Certificate. No private key
  information is shared. For manual verification, this value can be copied and saved as .cer file**
- `Signatures` refers to **This element contains the sub-elements of signatures corresponding to InputHash.**
- `DocSignature` refers to **This element will contain the Signed value in raw (PKCS#1) or raw( ECDSA ) or PKCS7 (CMS) signature format as per the request XML which will be verifiable against original document**

**Thanks every one.**

Comment: Are you using service to sign PDF or itext library, because to me it looks like you are mixing it together. It should be easy to sign with iText library, for example [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64678798/1651107). If you have a problem using iText library you should probably ask directly about it with your code shown.

Comment: @Piro I am using a service to sign PDF using itext pdf java library or any other java library

Comment: Most likely you'll eventually need the `DocSignature` but you will have to put the correct data into your request XML.

Comment: @mkl i have the proper docSignature received from the response using request xml.

Comment: Which PDF library do you want to use?

Comment: @mkl apache pdf box

Comment: Ok. Then you can simply start with the `CreateSignature` and `CreateSignatureBase` classes from the pdfbox-examples, remove all the `KeyStore` related code, and replace it with code based on your web service.